# Can't Find GDK in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-glass, google-gdk

Before I updated to 1.31 on Android Studio, I was able to use the GDK Preview without any issues. Now, I am not able to find the GDK, as Android Studio says it is "Not Installed" when it clearly is in the Android SDK Manager. I checked both SDK paths for Android Studio and SDK Manager and they are both pointing to `/Library/Java/Android/sdk`.

I ran a sample Glass project from Google and it ran successfully without any issues.

I don't understand why I can't create a new project anymore with the GDK! Has anyone had any similar issues with this update from Android Studio and can give me any words of advice? Thanks!

Comment: Did this folder exists? `sdk/add-ons/addon-google_gdk-google-19`

Comment: Yeah its in there. It must not have anything to do with the path because I was able to run a sample Glass project without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest release of Android Studio does not work with Glass. Fix: Use the working version 1.2.1.1 (http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/1-2-1-1). Worked for me.